# How to send notification using notification hubs as php backend

Tags: php, azure, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

Try to send the notification using PHP as back end follow the instruction as per link -

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-php-backend-how-to/

but through parse warning for "[" in notiicaitonhub.php line -

```
    if (in_array($notification->format, ["template", "apple", "gcm"])) {
    $contentType = "application/json";
} else {
    $contentType = "application/xml";
}
```

And notification is not delivered.

Comment: which PHP version do you have ? and can you paste the exact warning message ?

Comment: php version 5.3.13 and message - "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in D:\wamp\mpns\NotificationHub.php on line 73

Answer (score 0):

`PHP` version < `5.4` doesn't support short syntax array declaration i.e. using `[]` (square brackets)

Update your `PHP` version or for the time being you can try changing the arrays declared using `[]` to `array()` declaration. Here is your fixed code:

```
if (in_array($notification->format, array("template", "apple", "gcm"))) {
    $contentType = "application/json";
} else {
    $contentType = "application/xml";
}
```